# Display All Followed Users In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get all users that are followed by another user. My Follows table is like this **id, user_id, target_id**. I can get all target_id for a user but my problem is how do i now use the target_id to retrieve users on the users table. I have tried some methods but the best i got was only a single user instead of all users the current user is following. This is how my controller looks like. It only returns one user.

```
$follows = Follow::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

         foreach ($follows as $follows) {

         $followID = $follows->target_id;
         }

        $following = User::where('id', $followID)->get();
```

my user model

```
public function followers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Follow', 'target_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$following = User::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    $query->select('target_id')->from('follows')->where('user_id', auth()->id());
})->get();
```

Alternatively, you can [set up a `BelongsToMany` relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) in your `User` model.